# Requirements for installing a Helm chart on a multi-cluster Kubernetes platform

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-cluster

I have an umbrella Helm chart containing different sub-charts (including a RabbitMQ-ha). I am able to easily install this helm chart on a k8s cluster but I want to know is it possible to just install this helm chart (or any ready to use helm chart) on a multi-cluster k8s or I have to change the chart and make it compatible with a multi-cluster setup?

I have to mention that my chart requires dns and metric-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by multi-cluster Kubernetes clusters you mean using federation ([Federation v2](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubefed)) which syncs resources across clusters based on the user defined policies, e.g. ensure that Deployments created by helm exists in multiple clusters - in this case you use single umbrella Helm chart like you were working with single cluster.

If by multi-cluster you mean multiple standalone/self-contains clusters, then you need to have probably a customized version of the same umbrella chart with cloud provider specific values - check how to achieve that with the idea using one of the helmfile feature called templatization. [This](https://itnext.io/setup-your-kubernetes-cluster-with-helmfile-809828bc0a9f) article shows how to do that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I meant many k8s clusters that are connected to each other via federation as you mentioned.